# Go Echo not getting POST body from Vue

Tags: javascript, http, go, vue.js, axios

I have SignUp function and trying to get the body of a request which sending by Vue framework, but it's empty.

**Go**

```
type SignUpForm struct {
    Username string
    Email    string
    Password string
}

func SignUp(c echo.Context) error {
    form := SignUpForm{
        Username: c.FormValue("username"),
        Email:    c.FormValue("email"),
        Password: c.FormValue("password")}

    user := models.User{
        Username: form.Username,
        Email:    form.Email,
        Password: models.HashPassword(form.Password),
    }

    log.Printf("#####################")
    values, _ := c.FormParams()
    log.Printf("%v\n", values)
    log.Printf("%v", c.Response().Header())
    log.Printf("#####################")

    err := database.Connection().Create(&user).Error
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
    } else {
        return generateJwtToken(c, user)
    }
}
```

**Vue**

```
 sendForm: function() {
  var link = '/auth/sign_up'
  axios.post(link, {
    username: "test",
    email: "user@gmail.com",
    password: "password"
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(e.response)
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e.response)
  })
```

If I use Postman I  get this log information

```
2018/10/27 14:11:48 #####################
2018/10/27 14:11:48 map[email:[user@gmail.com] password:[password] username:[test]]
2018/10/27 14:11:48 map[Vary:[Origin] Access-Control-Allow-Origin:[*]]
2018/10/27 14:11:48 #####################
```

If I try to send by Vue I get nothing

```
2018/10/27 14:14:55 #####################
2018/10/27 14:14:55 map[]
2018/10/27 14:14:55 map[Vary:[Origin] Access-Control-Allow-Origin:[*]]
2018/10/27 14:14:55 #####################
```

I'm totally sure it's go/echo issue because I'm able to get those params in my rails app, so Vue sends them correctly.

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"test", "email"=>"user@gmail.com", "password"=>"password"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the params aren't passed trough url ? Try to debug it.  `fmt.Println("params:", c.QueryParams())`

Comment: @Зелёный yeah, totally. I can see the url in my browser console. `params: map[]`

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format I believe you're sending json with axios but attempting to read a urlencoded form with echo.

Comment: Have you tried a `Bind interface`? That is how I send data through `axios` and `vue` ```form := new(SignUpForm)
  if err = c.Bind(form); err != nil {
    return
  }```

Comment: @mkopriva you are correct. in your `vue` main.js add the following `axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @mkopriva stated `axios` does send as `json` but `echo` looks for `x-www-form-urlencoded`. In your `vue` add `axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` or pass the header in each `axios.post`

In echo you can `c.Bind` the request into your variable like below. That way you can receive `json` or `form` (postman for testing and `vue`)

```
type SignUpForm struct {
    Username string `json:"username" form:"username" query:"username"`
    Email    string `json:"email" form:"email" query:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password" form:"password" query:"password"`
}

func SignUp(c echo.Context) error {

    form := new(SignUpForm)

    if err := c.Bind(form); err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    }

    user := models.User{
        Username: form.Username,
        Email:    form.Email,
        Password: models.HashPassword(form.Password),
    }

    log.Printf("#####################")
    values, _ := c.FormParams()
    log.Printf("%v\n", values)
    log.Printf("%v", c.Response().Header())
    log.Printf("#####################")

    err := database.Connection().Create(&user).Error
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
    } else {
        return generateJwtToken(c, user)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just had to define json params in the struct. Thank you!